# How to get an integer from user in c++?

Tags: c++, iostream, cin, std

I can't get integer from user, when i try `cin >> n;` (where `n` is `int` variable)
it gives some strange `error`. Other inputs like character, double float works fine.
I was using **DevC++**, but now I also tried it on command line **gcc**, the error is still there :

> ```
> undefined reference to 'std::cin'
> undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
> ...
> ```

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;
  cin >> n;
}
```

**it works fine if I change n to a float type or double type variable.**

Tried on Bloodshed DevC++, 
MinGw gcc

Comment: Use `g++` not `gcc` when linking a C++ program.  The default set of libraries is different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `g++`  :

```
g++ program.cpp -o a.out
```

Or with `gcc` (If you add the ***`c++` runtime library***) :

```
gcc program.cpp -o a.out -lstdc++
```